# Why am I getting a javascript NaN error message?

Tags: javascript

Doing a project for my intro to javascript class and can't quite figure out why this isn't working. Can anyone help me out? Here is my code for the assignment.

```
//Declare variables
var guestsPerRoom;
var discount;
var goodView;
var totalCost;
var costPerNight;
var membership;

//prompt user to enter info based on their needs
guestsPerRoom = prompt("How many guests will be staying in this room? (Max 6)");
discount = prompt("Are you a member of AAA?");
goodView = prompt("Would you like a room with a good view? (10% Price Increase)");

//Calculate guests needs to total cost
totalCost = Number(totalCost);
discount = Number(discount);
costPerNight = Number(costPerNight);

//Output users total cost
if (guestsPerRoom === 1 || guestsPerRoom === 2) {
  costPerNight = 50;
  if (membership === 'Y') {
    discount = costPerNight * 0.85;
  }
  else if (membership === 'N') {
    discount = costPerNight;
  }
  if (goodView === 'Y') {
    totalCost = costPerNight * discount * 1.1;‹
  }
  else if (goodView === 'N') {
    totalCost = costPerNight * discount;
  }
}
 document.write("Total cost per night is $" + totalCost);
```

When I run the program, I am hoping to get the phrase "Total cost per night is $50(or whatever the total cost would be). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? My guess is that my totalCost variable is not defined, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Exactly what is the error you’re seeing? Please include the entire text.

Comment: What's with the `‹` character on the line `totalCost = costPerNight * discount * 1.1;‹`?

Comment: initialize the variables, you should also check after the input if the value was a number while (isNaN(variable)) { ask  again }

Comment: Also it is bad to have an `if` and `else if` without a final `else` as sometimes the code will do neither, and then the values will not be set as what's happened in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to convert to Number non numeric answers to these two questions:

```
discount = prompt("Are you a member of AAA?");
goodView = prompt("Would you like a room with a good view? (10% Price Increase)");

discount = Number(discount);
costPerNight = Number(costPerNight);
```

Of course those answers are not numbers. Hence the error.

Comment: `costPerNight` is not the result of the second question, and `discount` is, but shouldn't be, the result to the first.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like

```
discount = prompt("Are you a member of AAA?");
```

Should be

```
membership = prompt("Are you a member of AAA?");
```

since you have

```
 if (membership === 'Y') {
```

but you never set the membership variable.  And then you just need to remove this line:

```
discount = Number(discount);
```

Comment: I'd actually remove all those `Number(...)` lines. They don't do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with this code. First of all, `guestsPerRoom` gets a string value from the prompt, so the triple `===` 'strict' operator won't work if you compare it to a number. You either have to make sure they are the same type (both string or both number), or use the non-strict comparison `==`.

Then, `membership` doesn't ever get a value before your start using it in the ifs, since you store the result of the prompt inside `discount`.

Also, `totalCost = Number(totalCost)` will result in totalCost becoming `NaN`, since you didn't give it a value before. Since the other variables also have no, or incorrect, or unexpected values, your `if` tree is never entered, and `totalCost` never gets another value than the `NaN` it originally received. This is why you see NaN in the output.

A hint of advice: Use `console.log(totalCost)` to inspect `totalCost` (and same for other variables of course). You can a couple of lines in the code, so those values are outputted to the console (press F12 to open it). That way you can inspect values and the code path without blocking execution. You can also use the debugger to step through the code, but that's a bit harder to master.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned from `prompt` is a string (or null if cancelled), so when you try to compare the value to a number using `===` it will not match.

You could use the `==` operator to make a type relaxed comparison, but it's better to handle numbers as numbers rather than strings. Parse the value to a number, then either way of comparing them will work:

```
guestsPerRoom = parseInt(prompt("How many guests will be staying in this room? (Max 6)"), 10);
```

You assign the result from the membership question to the `discount` variable, it should be:

```
membership = prompt("Are you a member of AAA?");
```

In the next few lines you convert the values in `totalCost`, `discount` and `costPerNight` to numbers although you haven't assigned anything to them yet (except discount that was assigned the membership value).

When you set the `discount` value you use `costPerNight`, but you later multiply that value with `costPerNight` so that would make the total cost the square of `costPerNight`. Just assign the discount factor to the variable:

```
if (membership === 'Y') {
  discount = 0.85;
}
else if (membership === 'N') {
  discount = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your input against being a number since you are using "===" which cares about the type of the var, so you want to make sure that you are verifying the user input. any text input or "weird" input would result in a 'NaN' type.